# Make an Os X Smart folder containing only the first child folders of its parent folder

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, search

I am tryng to create a smart search that just lists the folders within a folder. The trouble is that, by default, the search goes within those folders and finds others. I just want those top level folders to show up.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to delimit the depth of search or specify a partial path in smart folders.

It is however, easy to use the find unix command to tag them as it does know about depth.

You could simply tag the desired folders with some label or meta-data and instead have your smart folder key on it.

This is obviously a bad solution if the folders change often as you would then have to have the tagging script running periodically or based on folder actions. Doable, but clunky.